# layout file name format magento 2

Tags: magento2

my **etc/frontend/routes.xml** is :

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="catalogsearch" frontName="catalogsearch">    <!--front name for the controller-->
        <module name="Tagalys_Tglssearch"/>
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

My controller paths are:

\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\Catalog\Category.php

\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\Catalog\CategoryController.php

\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\CatalogSearch\Result.php

\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController.php

is my layout file name correct ?

**catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_search/filter.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
  <referenceBlock name="product_searchlist_toolbar">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
    </body>
  </page>
```

Because my custom block is not at all getting called

```
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

public function __construct(
    /*passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class */    
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
     CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    /*passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class */    

    \Tagalys\Tglssearch\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory = $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory;
    $this->catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

      parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    ); 
    //$this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
}
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
         echo 'My block';
}
```

Comment: add complete catalogsearch_result_index.xml file for more debug

Comment: tats the completed code of the xml @Rakesh... wat did u ask?

Comment: you have to add whole file start with <?xml version="1.0"?> in above questions.

Comment: have updated @Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is incorrect format,
Your **`<page> node`** format is incorrect 
block with name **`product_searchlist_toolbar`** not available in magento 2. I have remove from below code, Remaining code are below you can set from below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_search/filter.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    </body>
  </page>
```

Comment: and the remaining part of the block is it correct? and file name?

Comment: Remaining all is correct with filename

Comment: I have a doubt as to from where we use that 'index' from the layout file name...i was assuming 'routerfrontName_controllerActionName_controllerName'.xml...    so it would be catalogsearch_catalogsearch_result.xml     correct me if im wrong

Comment: Could you please explain the proper way of using, im still confused

Comment: catalogsearch_result_index.xml is the correct file, this file is used when search result is display in site.

Comment: im using my custom search engine @Rakesh, not magento ones, i have given the file path of controller above

Comment: is thst correct? catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller is it the file name?

Comment: it is correct for , your controller path like catalogsearch/catalogsearch/resultcontroller.php

Comment: But why do i get this in system.log Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.          i still get blank page when i search for products

Comment: this error  is not for your module related and its not create any problem for you